# Automatically Adding IBOutlet to .h File with Storyboard

Tags: xcode, uistoryboard

I have been used to working with .XIB files until now where I am learning storyboarding. 
In all the online tutorials, it says to create a .h and .m file, split the view so you can see story board and code. Ctrl click from the control to the code page and when you release you will see a popover that will create your IBOutlet code (ivar, @property, etc).

I try to click and drag to the .h page and when I release I dont get a popover for being able to create the code for me.

The page name is the same as the UIViewController in Storyboard.

Any ideas why I am not getting a pop-over?

Comment: Did you set the custom class name? Its in the identity inspector (3rd tab)

Comment: Ill check that out... I think I might have missed that :(

Comment: Please put that in as an answer.... that was a silly mistake but it will probably done again by someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the Custom Class Name in the identity inspector (3rd tab)

Answer (score 1):

First check that the class you are referring in the XIB is same as you have created if not then you can change the class of the current view controller of XIB from identity inspector to the custom class that  you have created

It also happens in the case your class is not match with same as XIB class for that you can go to just above the canvas and class selection to automatic which gives you the current class and then you will be able to create an outlet through drop drop method.